# Cчитывание информации о папке и вывод в консоль с помошью java.nio

Tags: java

```
package com.javarush.task.task31.task3113;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.*;


import static java.lang.System.out;

/* Что внутри папки?

Что внутри папки?

Напиши программу, которая будет считать подробную информацию о папке и выводить ее на консоль.

Первым делом считай путь к папке с консоли.

Если введенный путь не является директорией — выведи «[полный путь] — не папка» и заверши работу.

Затем посчитай и выведи следующую информацию:

Всего папок — [количество папок в директории]

Всего файлов — [количество файлов в директории и поддиректориях]

Общий размер — [общее количество байт, которое хранится в директории]

Используй только классы и методы из пакета java.nio. */

public class Solution {

   static int countPapok =0;

    static int countFiles =0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String path = scan.nextLine();

        Path pathFile = Paths.get(path);

        if(!Files.isDirectory(pathFile))

        {



            out.println(pathFile.toAbsolutePath()+" — не папка");

            return;

        }
        else

        {
            Files.walkFileTree(pathFile,new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){

                @Override

                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                    countFiles++;

                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, 

                   BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                     countPapok++;

                    return  FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        }

        out.println("Всего папок — "+(countPapok-1));
        out.println("Всего файлов — "+countFiles);
        out.println("Общий размер — "+Files.size(pathFile));


      scan.close();

    }


}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема (не проходит валидатор).
Вроде, все работает (может быть, я неправильно считаю количество папок?).
Рекурсию использовать нельзя.

Comment: Советую оборачивать `Scaner` в `try-with-resources`. Не понятно какой валидатор? И что вы подразумеваете под без рекурсий? Ведь `walkFileTree` - рекурсивно обходит. Может быть вы имели ввиду без циклических-рекурсий?

Comment: `Files.size` возвращает размер файла из аргумента, для папки результат не определен, но точно не равен сумме всех содержащихся внутри файлов.

Comment: Ясно, тоесть там где я считаю количество файлов мне паралельно стоит считать их вес и добавлять в общую переменную веса?